# Using double, return string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, double

In the application I'm writing, one of the methods allows for the numbers the user entered to be turned into letters.

For example, the user will be entering grades (as doubles) and the program will decide (when the criteria is met) to return the letter associated with the number. Initially, I had it written like this:

```
public void GetGrade(double scores)
Console.Write("Score of {0} earns: ", score);

if (score >= 95.0)
    Console.WriteLine("A+");
else if (score >= 90.0)
    Console.WriteLine("A");
else if (score >= 85.0)
    Console.WriteLine("B+");
else if (score >= 80.0)
    Console.WriteLine("B");
else if (score >= 75.0)
    Console.WriteLine("C+");
else if (score >= 70.0)
    Console.WriteLine("C");
else if (score >= 65.0)
    Console.WriteLine("D+");
else if (score >= 60.0)
    Console.WriteLine("D");
else
    Console.WriteLine("F");
```

But it needs to be written with a RETURN in mind.
So, I think it should be public string `GetGrade(double scores)`
And since it's in an array I would need:

```
foreach(double score in scoress)
{
THE CODE I POSTED ABOVE
}
```

Except I'd change all the `console.writeline`s to return.
However, when I do that I get a syntax error telling me:

> A local variable named score cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'score', which is already used in parent or current scope to denote something else.

So, I gather that I cannot use `score` because the header already contains `score`.
How do I go about getting this to work the way I want it to?

Comment: Looks like an obvious name collision. Could you post the whole piece of code?

Comment: This one method of nine or so. That'd be quite a bit.
I manged to use that same foreach statement in three other methods, but those didn't have the exact same header names like this one does. So I assume you're right in this assessment of name collision.
I'm just now sure how to change it.

Comment: Try cutting out the code until (a) it's simple enough to post here or (b) the problem goes away.  In the case of (b), the name collision is occurring in the deleted code.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is confusing.

> And since its in an array...

but none of your examples include an array.  Your method would work fine as

```
public string ToGrade(double score)
{
  if (score >= 95.0)
        return "A+";
    else if (score >= 90.0)
        return "A";
  /* snip */
    else
        return "YOU GET NOTHING!  YOU LOSE!  GOOD DAY SIR!";
}
```

Seems to me your method isn't the issue, its the code in which you're calling it that's the problem.  You'll have to post that to get a correct answer to your question.

If you're getting an array of "grades" and transforming them into a bunch of letter grades, you'll have to have an array to store the letter grades.  Something like this may be what you need:

```
public static string[] ToGrade(double[] grades)
{
  // sanity checks go here
  string[] result = new string[grades.Length];
  for(int i = 0; i < grades.Length; i++)
    result[i] = ToGrade(grades[i]);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the variable name in your for loop.

```
Foreach (double s in scores){...}
```

I assume `scores` is an array of doubles. Is this correct?

If you return from an array you will only get the grade for the first score... Maybe you should return a correlating collection of grades.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = [
    [95.0, "A+"],
    [90.0, "A"],
    [85.0, "B+"],
    [80.0, "B"],
    [75.0, "C+"],
    [70.0, "C"],
    [65.0, "D+"],
    [60.0, "D"]
];

 for (var i in list)
    if (score >= list[0])
        return list[1];
 return "F";
```

Comment: Its in c#, which is why you're gonna get some -1's (not from me, tho)

Comment: I wish people would post other language to questions labeled 'homework' since I use that tag for learning examples. +1